# What is the difference between needClientAuth vs wantClientAuth in Jetty SSL module?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I'm trying to enable client authentication for Jetty server.

I found two configurations `needClientAuth` and `wantClientAuth`. Most of the places `needClientAuth` is being used, then what is the purpose of `wantClientAuth`?

Answer (score 2):

One scenario if you want to enforce [mTLS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/access-management/what-is-mutual-tls/) only for certain clients. So you have `wantClientAuth` option, then you have a filter that checks certain clients succeeded mTLS.